# ToggleButton not working

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

I'm new to android. 
I tried to create a simple toggle button and catch it's state change. But it crashes when I run it on my device.

Here is the MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.addimagebutton;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ToggleButton tbSwitch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tbSwitch = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.swButton);
        tbSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener toggleListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Here is activity_main.xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/swButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to run this code without the listener objects.(commenting those) But it gave me the same result.

Comment: You are casting a switch to Toggle Button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting a switch to Toggle Button so it gives you `ClassCastException`..

Change this

```
 <Switch
    android:id="@+id/swButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch"
    android:textOff="Off"
    android:textOn="On" />
```

into

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/swButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch"
    android:textOff="Off"
    android:textOn="On" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Used `ToggleButton` instead of `Switch` like

```
   <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/swButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch"
    android:textOff="Off"
    android:textOn="On"" />
```

Becoz your layout contains `Switch` and you cast it with `ToggleButton`. That's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Change `switch` to `ToggleButton`

```
   <ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/swButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in your xml you should use ToggleButton instead of Switch - it should look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ToogleButton
    android:id="@+id/swButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch"
    android:textOff="Off"
    android:textOn="On" />
```